# Disabling alert window in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, javascript

i am using VS 2005 and WebBrowser control. When i using component to navigate to specified page i get scenario error, like "On this page javascript scenario error" and two buttons: yes or no executing scenario. How to prevent alert windows and continue browsing without this messages?

Comment: Do you want to disable the script errors? or do want to disable confirm boxes?

Comment: I want to disable confirm boxes.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. :(

Comment: It's an IE's setting. You can change it by yourself in Browser Options

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
HtmlElement head = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = WebBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
string alertBlocker = @"window.alert = function () { }; window.confirm=function () { };";
element.text = alertBlocker;
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Source : 
http://moshez.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/c-disable-alert-box-javascript-in-c.html

Comment: Very good, Very good. I don't know why previous answer accepted and high upvoted? it is deserve to acception.

Comment: To a certain degree what Farzin is stating is correct. Except; OP is not asking to suppress Alert. He is asking to suppress JS error popup.
Moshes fix is for the Alert.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Private Sub WebBrowser1_StatusTextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.StatusTextChanged
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim head As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")(0)
        Dim script As HtmlElement
        script = WebBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script")
        script.SetAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
        Dim alertBlocker As String = "window.alert = function () { }; window.confirm=function () { }; "
        script.SetAttribute("text", alertBlocker)
        head.AppendChild(script)
    End Sub
```

Comment: VB C#... Potato potato.   Its all .NET anyway :)